# How do I compare the output of a program to lines of a text file?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a text file that contains a number on each line. There are 5 lines.

I also have a program that runs and prints out 5 numbers, one on each line. The output of the program should match the number on each line of the text file.

How do I check if the numbers are equal?

I'm using bash

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the program that generates the numbers is called `program` and that the file with the reference numbers is called `file`.  To compare them:

```
program | cmp - file || echo "Fail"
```

`cmp` is a program that compares two files and one of those files can be stdin, denoted by `-`.  So, `cmp - file` compares what is in `file` with what is provided on stdin by `program`.

If you want a detailed report on how the two differ, use `diff` in place of `cmp`:

```
program | diff - file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n 'The numbers are '
[[ $(< numsfile) == $(< ./numsprog ) ]] && echo 'the same' || echo different
```

This assumes that there are no spaces or other non-numeric characters, other than newlines,  in either the file `numsfile`, or in the output of the program `numsprog`.

Comment: The original, tested and working, code was broken by replacing `$( ./numsprog )` (get the output produced by running `./numsprog`) with `$(< ./numsprog)` (get the contents of the file `./numsprog`).

Answer (score 0):

From the most complex case: you can compare output of two programs

```
diff -q <(seq 1 5) <(seq 2 6)
```

You can replace any of the arguments with `-` (meaning stdin) if you prefer pipes

```
seq 1 5 | diff -q - <(seq 2 6)
```

To solve your problem, replace first `seq` with you program and `<(...)` with your file name.